# I don't understand the argument passing of the lambda expression in the listener

Tags: java, android, kotlin

It wasn't long after I started studying Kotlin.

There are parts that I don't understand about the delivery of lambda expressions in the Android listener.

**In JAVA**

```
botton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
                
     }
});
```

i understand this code.

I understand this code. An anonymous object is created and passed as a parameter of `setOnClickListener`.

**In Kotlin**

```
button.setOnClickListener(object: View.OnClickListener {
       override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
           TODO("Not yet implemented")
       }
})
```

And I understand this code too. I understand it as it is a way to create anonymous objects similar to Java.

But

**In Lamda of Kotlin**

```
button?.setOnClickListener { }
```

I don't understand how this code works.

The lambda expressed here should be passed as an argument of `setOnClickListener`.

`onClick()` is an implementation function of the `OnClickListener` interface, how is it possible to be passed to `setOnClickListener`?

I don't understand well.

Isn't `setOnClickListener` an `OnClickListener` interface `object` that should be passed?

Comment: Do you understand the Java code `button.setOnClickListener(v -> {})`?

Comment: Well, roughly I understand

Comment: I think your Kotlin code does effectively the same thing. Only difference is that you can get rid of the parenthesis and don't have to name the single argument of the `onClick` method.

Comment: You should probably have a look at the lambda documentation here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html. Especially pay attention to the *trailing lambdas*  and *it* sections.

Comment: Also take a look into SAM conversions: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#sam-conversions

Comment: @HenryTwist thank you. What I'm asking seems to mean a SAM conversion, right?

Comment: Yes exactly, as `OnClickListener` is a single method interface, it gets converted. So it's really just convenient syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lambda IS being passed as an argument to `setOnClickListener`!

You can test this by trying `button?.setOnClickListener({ })` and noticing it still compiles.

Android Studio then suggests changing it to `button?.setOnClickListener(){ }`, as [Kotlin's coding convention](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#lambdas) dictates:

> If a call takes a single lambda, pass it outside of parentheses whenever possible.

This gives us `button?.setOnClickListener(){ }`.

The `()` is marked as redundant, due to "*Remove unnecessary parentheses from function call with lambda*" leading to... `button?.setOnClickListener { }`!

*Note: You can ctrl / cmd click the function name and the signature shows `public void setOnClickListener(@Nullable OnClickListener l)`*

Comment: In `button?.setOnClickListener({ })`, `{ }` is expressed as a lambda of `onClick()`. And in Kotlin, if the only parameter is a lambda expression, you can express it by subtracting `{}` out. And finally `()` can be omitted. Was it this way?

Eventually `{ }` is passed to `setOnClickListener`, but is it possible because it is an implementation lambda of the `OnClickListener interface`?